# Add Items Dynamically to New Page - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to Add TextBoxes dynamically, by asking user the number of textBoxes.
This code is working and but adding items to present place.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?shouldDownload=true",     UriKind.Relative)); //Naviagte on new page
int num;
int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num); //Converting textbox to int
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    TextBox newtext = new TextBox();
    newtext.Text = i.ToString();
    newtext.Margin = new Thickness(300, (i * 80), 0, 0);
    newtext.Width = 124;
    newtext.Height = 68;
    //button.VerticalAlignment = 234;
    //Add contentpanel to your page if there's not one already.
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(newtext);
    newtext.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But I want to add these Items to new page (i.e: Page1) not here.

Help will be appropriated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing this to your second page via the navigation params

```
string num = textBox1.Text;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?shouldDownload=true&num="+num,     UriKind.Relative)); //Naviagte on new page
```

In your second page your parse the result within the OnNavigatedTo method

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string numValue;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("num", out numValue))
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(numValue);
        // add 'em here
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think you can send integer the way you are sending it.. only strings can be send...

Comment: it works fine but you cannot send it as a integer ... in your case it is still recieved as a string so that is the thing i was talking about that you cannot send integer .....

Comment: It sends it as a string but then you parse it into an integer, either via int.TryParse or Convert.ToInt32. It really does work.

Comment: Look at the sample I provided. If the QueryString contains the value it converts it to an int

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?shouldDownload=true&msg=" + extBox1.Text,     UriKind.Relative));
```

then on the onnavigation method of the new page do this ..

```
 IDictionary<string, string> parameters = NavigationContext.QueryString;
 string number= parameters["msg"];
```

then do your code from 
`int num =0;` and so on

I hope that it might help